# Was Patent ever used?

Tags: us2821692

In reference to the patent: [US2821692](https://www.google.com/patents/US2821692)

I found a letter in my grandfathers paperwork and after doing a bit of research I found this website.  This was my grandfather's patent and I was wondering if there is way to find any more information on this patent...was it ever used etc.  I don't even know if patent is obsolete.  It almost looks like the power cord surge protectors we use today.

Comment: It doesn't look like a surge protector to me - more like a multi-way extension block, but without the holes to guide the plugs.  I have no idea how you find out if it wa ever used, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.yankodesign.com/2010/07/20/power-line-up/ seems pretty similar.
Comments in http://gizmodo.com/5592067/absolutely-genius-slide-your-plugs-into-slots-instead-of-individual-holes state that this kind of product was in use a few decades ago.

A Google search for "slot type power outlet" brought up the above links.